# Unable to record audit log for associations using PaperTrail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

User have relations with user_favourite_locations and preferred_locations. My user model code:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :preferred_locations, through: :user_favourite_locations
    has_many :user_favourite_locations
    has_paper_trail class_name: 'UserVersion',
                  only: [ :fb_uid, :favourite_location_ids ],
                  meta: {business_id: Proc.new{|o| o.business_id }},
                  on: [:update, :destroy]
end
```

Comment: With "_ids" fields it is a tricky part in rails. You have to check `ids_writer` and find they way to hook on it while it changes: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/93c94973ab574083a8cd1868aae03993ca156c34/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L56

Comment: There are no other way at the moment in rails core. This is one of the issues, especially when you work with singular / collections, there are many differences between them.

Comment: You may also be interested in https://github.com/westonganger/paper_trail-association_tracking

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This gem do not support the associated object data log features